# Fixed block element hides on window resize

Tags: css, positioning

I noticed a behavior that drives me crazy.

I have two divs, that have both similar css:

```
.one, .two {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 6%
}
```

One div is for navigation, and other is for content, that has max 300px height. The problem is, that if the user resizes the browser window to really small one, the scrollbar is not shown.

I tried to change position to absolute, but then the ajaxify plugin breaks the position if new page is loaded. I couldn't find other ideas, how to position those divs at fixed position at bottom.

p.s. I pasted a sample test on http://pastebin.com/Bp1490dj

Comment: can you maybe put the example to http://www.jsfiddle.net, that really helps alot

Answer (score 1):

the background-green div is at the bottom with position:absolute;

from what I know a position:fixed; and or position:absolute; will never make a scroll. (please correct me if I'm wrong) so a way to go arround this is to set a min-height to body

```
body {
    min-height:200px;
}
```

have a look at the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/u2ZWa/

also, there is a fix with a scroll now. But you have to know the fixed elements will never be scrollable because they're fixed

Comment: Thanks, for the tip. I positioned it before with absolute, but other problem exist then: If you resize the height of the window to a smaller one ( e.g. 250px), the text disappears and cannot be read, see
http://jsfiddle.net/RjM8F/

A scrollbar is shown, but it is not possible to scroll to top, but just to bottom, where only white space exists

Comment: @sonne the scroll bar is showing because body {min-height:350px;} if you remove that there is no scroll bar. so now, if you scroll, you scroll the body. thats why you are scolling into white space.. have you got a link to a page or can you upload a picture to show what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Scrollbars are not compatible with a fixed positioning.